# Can´t rebuild node-gyp

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I´ve already installed node modules, but I had an issue with bcrypt and to solve it y tried to rebuild node-gyp, but it launches an error:
[image]

Comment: Please try to delete your node-gyp directory in from root ```rm -rf !/.node-gyp``` and then rebuild and please let me know the node version

Comment: It didn´t work. I am using node v 6.10.1

Comment: I think node 6.10.1 has some issues with it because i also faced same issues with version 6.10.1.Please try with node-v6.9.2 and if you want to keep both 6.10.1 and 6.9.2 then please install nvm

Comment: I already installed version 6.9.2 and I still have that problem. another suggestion????

Comment: Use following steps which worked for me when i am trying to install lwip
First install node-gyp globally
Then install node-gyp locally
Then install bcrypt

Comment: I made it that way, and gyp installed successfully. But when I tried to install bcrypt it fails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153372/discussion-between-yanet-pedraza-and-atul-agrawal).